# PlantUml component relative posithion strange behaviour

Tags: plantuml

Here is my simplified component diagram:

```
@startuml
component TopLeft
component TopRight
component BottomStretch {
    'portin port_test
}
TopLeft -[hidden]r- TopRight
TopLeft -[hidden]d- BottomStretch
TopRight -[hidden]d- BottomStretch
@enduml
```

, and as long as BottomStretch is empty, every component is allocated as expected.

[image: PlantUML image]

But if we put something inside the BottomStretch component (removing comment in this example), this springs to the top right:

[image]

Is there some way to control component relative location?

And one additional question: is it possible to stretch the bottom component so that its left coincides with left of TopLeft, and right - with right of TopRight?

Thank in advance for all comments and suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you un-hide the links that try to force the layout, you can see that the connections are going to the left side of the BottomStretch component. I think this is because `port_test` is now the top element in that group.

Using that hypothesis as a clue, I changed just one of the links to link to the (new) top element (`port_test`):

```
@startuml
component TopLeft
component TopRight
component BottomStretch {
    portin port_test
}
TopLeft -r- TopRight
TopLeft -d- BottomStretch
TopRight -d- port_test
@enduml
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Hiding the links (`[hidden]`) and making both vertical ones go to `port_test` should give you the result you expect (click the image to see the code):

[image]

Comment: thank you! the unhiding idea helped. and I've found one solution more:

Comment: sorry, could not manage to make a new line... one more solution: use double dashes instead of one:  TopRight -d-- BottomStretch

Comment: @user9893356 yes, the "longer" line makes the rank different, which causes the element to drop down. That solution might actually be cleaner.